# How can we store Canvas image to the server by using struts2 mvc architecture

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, html5-canvas, getter-setter

Here's the ajax call request

```
//sending request to action
var canvas=document.getElementById('can');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
$.ajax({    type: 'POST',  
            url: "/FMVMLAST/Canvasimage.action?img64="+dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""), 
            dataType: 'json', 
            async: false , 
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
            success: function(data){}
});
```

Following java code will take request and convert base64 data into `image/png` format and stores it to the server.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class Canvasimage extends ActionSupport{
String img64= ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("img64");


public String Canvasimage()
{
    try{
    byte[] imgData = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(img64 );
    BufferedImage bfi = ImageIO.read((ImageInputStream) new ByteArrayInputStream(imgData));    
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(bfi,"png", outputfile);
    bfi.flush();

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("In canvas"+e.getMessage());}
    return "success";
}

public String getImg64() {
    return img64;
}

public void setImg64(String img64) {
    this.img64 = img64;
}

}
```

I have added the action in struts.xml

```
<action name="Canvasimage" class="user.actions.Canvasimage" method="Canvasimage">   
           <result type="json"></result>
</action>
```

Whenever I make this request console show me the 404 error Can anyone tell me the what went wrong in the code.

**EDIT**

send request using ajax

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('can');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var data = {
        img64:dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""),
    };

$.ajax( 
        {   
            type: 'POST',  
            url: "/FMVMLAST/Canvasimage", 
            data:data,
            success: function(data){}
        });
```

struts.xml file

```
<struts>

    <bean type="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest" name="jakartaStream" class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest" scope="default" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.parser" value="jakarta-stream" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">
     <action name="Canvasimage" class="user.actions.Canvasimage" method="Canvasimage">   
            <result type="json"></result>
    </action>
</package>
```

java class

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class Canvasimage extends ActionSupport{

    private String img64;
    public byte[] valueDecoded;

    public String Canvasimage()
    {
        setImg64(img64);
        System.out.println(""+img64);
        try{

              byte[] decoded_id=valueDecoded;
              FileOutputStream file1 = new  FileOutputStream("C:\\image.png");




              file1.write(decoded_id);
              file1.close();

            System.out.println("incanvas"+decoded_id);
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("In canvas"+e);}
        return "success";
    }


    public String getImg64() {
        return img64;
    }


    public void setImg64(String img64) {
        this.img64 = img64;
        toImg64Byte();
    }


    private void toImg64Byte() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] img=img64.getBytes();
         this.valueDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(img);
    }

}
```

Comment: And **don't** get parameters like this `ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("img64");`.

Comment: thank you for your response but there is problem when i get the parameter in the java class console showing the error    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

Comment: tell me how should i get the base64 data in String in Canvasimage class now it showing me null value

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sending such a long param through querystring, in a POST call ? :|

Use POST parameters:

```
var dataURL = document.getElementById('can').toDataURL("image/png"); 

var data = {
    img64 : dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")
}

$.ajax({
   type : 'POST',  
    url : "/FMVMLAST/Canvasimage.action",
   data : data
...
```

You are probably hitting some querystring length cap, or the data you are sending is not valid json, so post it without the json datatype.

Also declare your variables with private qualifier, with public getters and setters, avoiding the manual read from request:

```
private String img64;

public String getImg64() {
    return img64;
}

public void setImg64(String img64) {
    this.img64 = img64;
}
```

Comment: yes i used get.. set.. methods but String variable is null and for further it gives me null pointer exception

Comment: i have added a action of struts.xml please tell me is right way to do

Comment: You have an unwanted `,` at the end of your data {} param

Comment: Also remember to always specify charset when using `getBytes()`, like `getBytes("UTF-8");`, and BTW you don't even need that method because [Base64.decodeBase64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29) has a method accepting Strings in input too, so the conversion to byte[] is superfluous.